# How do I find which register attribute to use in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am testing out the results of the register commands and it yields different attribute for various tasks: failures, msg, stderr, err..etc

```
- yum:
        name: packagenotfound
        state: present
        ignore_errors: yes
        register: command_result


      - debug:
              msg: "{{ command_result }}"

ok: [ansible] => {
"msg": {
    "changed": false,
    "failed": true,
    "failures": [
        "No package packagenotfound available."
    ],
    "msg": "Failed to install some of the specified packages",
    "rc": 1,
    "results": []
}}
```

And

```
 - lvg:
        pvs: /dev/sddnotfound
        vg: vgdata
        ignore_errors: yes
        register: command_result


      - debug:
              msg: "{{ command_result }}"

ok: [ansible] => {
"msg": {
    "changed": false,
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "Device /dev/sddnotfound not found."
}
```

And

```
  - shell: thiscommandwontwork
        ignore_errors: yes
        register: command_result


      - debug:
              msg: "{{ command_result }}"

ok: [ansible] => {
"msg": {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "thiscommandwontwork",
    "delta": "0:00:00.002560",
    "end": "2020-02-05 04:24:35.297556",
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 127,
    "start": "2020-02-05 04:24:35.294996",
    "stderr": "/bin/sh: thiscommandwontwork: command not found",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "/bin/sh: thiscommandwontwork: command not found"
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

And

```
- lvol:
        lv: lvdata
        vg: vgroup
        size: 2000M
        ignore_errors: yes
        register: command_result


      - debug:
              msg: "{{ command_result }}"

ok: [ansible] => {
"msg": {
    "changed": false,
    "err": "  Volume group \"vgroup\" not found\n  Cannot process volume group vgroup\n",
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "Volume group vgroup does not exist.",
    "rc": 5
}
```

Now if I tried to use `when: '"xxx" in command_result.err'` with yum task for example, it will result in dict_object not found error.

Is there a way to find out which attribute to use without testing?

Comment: No, there is no way of knowing which attribute to use without testing. Although what you are trying to accomplish in the provided examples, look like you only need to find out if the ansible task failed, for which case you do have the '"failed":true', that you are ignoring when setting "ignore_errors: yes" for those tasks. So, if the question is if there is some consistent way to evaluate outputs, no, there is not. If your question is for a particular case, can you please be more precise in what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping there would be a consistent way. In particular, it would be useful to know when running against specific conditions such as disk availability which attribute to look for, in this case it would be 'in .err' So it's rather confusing that two related modules 'lvg, lvol' return different attributes. To find device availability in 'lvg' I would have to use 'in .msg' in case I needed to run a condition against the return value.

Comment: There are ways to know the registered structure before hand, although testing is the probably the fastest one. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing is definitely the easiest and fastest way to have a look at the content of your registered var in several situation and to take decisions on how to use it in your playbook.

Meanwhile, there are ways to have a global knowledge of what is returned in your registered var from the documenations:

1. There is a page on [Common modules return values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#common-return-values)
2. Modules returning specific values usually document them on each relevant doc page. Here is an example for the [`stat` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/stat_module.html#return-values)
3. You should also be aware that the global register structure is changed when using a loop by addind a top level `results` list, as explained in [registering variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables)

Knowing what **could** be in your register does not mean it **will** be. Your example mentions the (undocumented...) `err` attribute for the `lvol` module, which will only be available for an `lvol` task in error. You can work around such cases by using [tests](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html) (like `my_register is failed`) or defaulting values with the [`default` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I learned about tests from your answer. Although it can be limited when running against different results from the same task: disk 'not found' or 'insufficient' disk space. In that case iterating through the .err string values become necessary:  when: "'not found' in command_result.err"
when: "'insufficient' in command_result.err"